# Magento 2 Image upload on CMS page

Tags: cms-pages, image-preview

```
<field name="page_image"> 
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">image</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Banner Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">image</item> 
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Image uploaded successfully & saved in database also. But I can not preview the image in the edit screen. How to preview the image with delete checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the fileuploader uses a specific array to preview the image and you have to create it manually.

You have to extend the source defined in:

```
<item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
```

And extend the DataProvider in `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider" type="Dexanet\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider"/>
```

You have to extend the `getData()` method like:

```
public function getData() {
  $data = parent::getData();

  foreach ($data as $pageId => $page) {
    if (isset($page['header_image'])) {
      unset($data[$pageId]['header_image']);
      $fileName = $page['header_image'];

      $serverPath = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
          ->getAbsolutePath() . $this->imageUploader->getBasePath() . "/" . $fileName;
      $fullPath = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
          \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
        ) . $this->imageUploader->getBasePath() . "/" . $fileName;

      if (file_exists($serverPath)) {
        $stat = stat($serverPath);
        $mime = mime_content_type($serverPath);

        $data[$pageId]["header_image"][0]['name'] = $fileName;
        $data[$pageId]["header_image"][0]['url'] = $fullPath;
        $data[$pageId]['header_image'][0]['size'] = isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0;
        $data[$pageId]['header_image'][0]['type'] = $mime;
      }
    }
  }

  return $data;
}
```